# What would please Lord Hanuman more - chanting Hanuman Chalisa or chanting Rama naam?

Tags: rama, hanuman

Lord Rama would probably want his devotee to be glorified above him, and Srila Prabhupada also states many times that Lord Sri Krishna says that worship of the devotee is higher than My worship - http://www.prabhupadaconnect.com/The-Highest-Form-of-Worship.html, https://vaniquotes.org/wiki/Worship_of_the_devotee_is_considered_more_effective_than_direct_worship_of_the_Lord

So I was thinking that Lord Rama would want Hanumanji to be pleased before pleasing him directly, and so I came to the question of what would please Hanumanji more, Rama naam, or Hanuman Chalisa. Hanumanji would probably want us to serve his Master and chant Rama naam directly. Do you see the conundrum? What would please Hanumanji more out of the two? Also, Hanuman Chalisa is written by another pure devotee of Lord Rama, Shri Tulsidas Goswami, so it becomes even more potent since it is glorification of a pure devotee of Lord Rama by another pure devotee of Lord Rama. However, everyone knows the power of Rama naam - http://lordrama.co.in/glory-of-rama-naam.html. Please help.

Answer (score 8):

"The Ramayana Dhyana slokam"

> यत्र यत्र रघुनाथकीर्तनं तत्र तत्र कृतमस्तकांजलिम् ।
>
> बाष्पवारिपरिपूर्णलोचनं मारुतिं नमत राक्षसान्तकम् ॥

Yatra Yatra Raghunaatha-Kiirtanam Tatra Tatra Krta-Mastaka-Anjalim
Vaasspa-Vaari-Paripuurnnaa-Locanam Maarutim Namata Raakssasa-Antakam ||

Meaning:
1: Wherever the Glories of Raghunatha are Sung, there, with Hands held over His Bowed Head in Salutation, ...
2: ... and Eyes Filled with Tears, Maruti (Bhakta Hanuman) is Present; I Salute Maruti Who puts an End to the Rakshasas.

It is clear from this shloka that by chanting "Raam Naam", Lord Hanumanji's presence & blessings can be sought and this is a sure shot & bulletproof way to seek blessings of both, Shree Raam & Shri Hanuman.

Comment: Where is this quote from?

Comment: This is in "The Ramayana Dhyana slokam". I have edited the answer.

Comment: I haven't accepted this answer because it doesn't explicitly state how Rama naam is better than Hanuman Chalisa. It also doesn't state whether Hanumanji blesses the devotee, only that he is present.

Comment: Accepting an answer or not is at the sole discretion of OP. No prob. Just to mention 2 things -- 1) Pl. don't overthink in this matter. This is not a materialistic business. It sounds like a "Baniya" thinking that "Which client would give me more money? I will entertain that client". In Sanskrut, it is well said that "संशयात्मा विनश्यति |"  Kindly don't take it as offence. Just my feelings. Accept it or discard if you wish... 2) Presence of Hanumanji is greatest thing in the world. Pl. don't say that "...only that he is present...". If one can attain it, there is no greater achievement.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am the OP, and I realize that I am undervaluing Lord Hanuman's darshan.

Answer (score 4):

Hanuman Chalisa comes with a lot of material benedictions. If you prayed to Lord Hanuman just to glorify him without any desire for material benefits it's good. If chanted it with a desire to obtain Rama Bhakti that is also good.

Quoting from [Krishna book](https://www.vedabase.com/en/kb/53) by Srila Prabhupada.

> Ordinary people pray to Goddess Durgā for material wealth, fame, profit, strength and so on; Rukmiṇī, however, desired to have Kṛṣṇa for her husband and therefore prayed that the deity be pleased with her and bless her with that benediction. Since she desired only Kṛṣṇa, her worship of the demigods is not condemned.

Besides Goswami Tulsidas writes in Hanuman Chalisa.

> TUMHARE BHAJAN RAM KO PAVE

So it's fine to chant Hanuman Chalisa desiring Rama Bhakti and Rama Bhakti alone.

That would please Lord Hanuman and make you start chanting Lord Rama's name.

Comment: The answer seems vague. OP's Q is very specific -- "What would please Hanumanji more out of the two?". He is not seeking whether "it is fine to chant Hanuman Chalisa desiring Rama Bhakti". Further, there are 2 points. 1) The url talks about Krushna Bhakti. 2) Reference should be from an authenticated scripture.

Comment: So if I start chanting Lord Rama's name, I should do that alone and leave chanting Hanuman Chalisa? See, my aim is to worship Lord Hanuman, as Srila Prabhupada says devotee worship is higher than God worship. The way you are putting it, it seems Rama naam is higher than Hanuman Chalisa, and HC should be used as a means to attain attachement to Rama naam.

Comment: For Hanuman, Ram is everything. If you chant 1 time Lord Ram with full devotion itself Hanuman will bless you automatically! Or you can also chant Hanuman chalisa with full devotion - Sri Ram and Hanuman will also bless you!!! ! You can follow either way but choose 1 way and stick to it!

Comment: @AkshayKumarS ,+1.  I ve answered on the same lines.

Comment: Akshay has summed it nicely . But best prayer to Lord Hanuman should be only to glorify Him and to get devotion to Lord Rama not for anything else.

Comment: @vineet "2) reference should be from authenticated scripture", it is a citable source in HSE

Answer (score 2):

I am one of the Hanuman Devotee. I think chanting Ram naam would please hanuman ji more than Chalisa as Chanting Ram naam gave soul power to Hanuman ji. If you read Ramayana, there was various situation when Hanuman ji chanted Ram naam and he found solution like Creating bridge between India and Srilanka.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism! Personal practices are not considered answers here!

Comment: I know people are mentioning lack of sources but I appreciate you posting your personal practice. What would you recommend to chant if you had to choose one to please Lord Hanuman - Rama naam or the Hanuman Chalisa?

Comment: @Yatish you did not answer the question. Please read the question carefully before answering. I have downvoted it.

Comment: There is a bhajan " Ram se bada Ram ka naam". Further Hanuman is pleased and present whenever Ram Naam Japan is done. I therefore feel Ram Naam is more pleasing to Hanuman than praise to him as in Hanuman Chalisa. This is a personal opinion.

Comment: I undeleted your answer. But you answer still has irrelevant information and add sources for info you added. Else, it will be considered as opinion and your answer may be deleted.

Comment: @Yatish Bathla, also when he had to jump across the ocean and Jambavan reminded him of his powers, only Rama naam helped him take a mightly leap.