# What is the result of worshipping Lord Sri Nityananda Rama Chandra Prabhu only/exclusively?

Tags: krishna, worship, gaudiya-vaishnavism, prabhupada

Srila Prabhupada says here https://prabhupadabooks.com/cc/adi/8/31 that -

> A neophyte student who is not sufficiently educated or enlightened should not indulge in the worship of Śrī Rādhā and Kṛṣṇa or the chanting of the Hare Kṛṣṇa mantra. Even if he does so, he cannot get the desired result. One should therefore chant the names of Nitāi-Gaura and worship Them without false prestige. Since everyone within this material world is more or less influenced by sinful activities, in the beginning it is essential that one take to the worship of Guru-Gaurāṅga and ask their favor, for thus despite all his disqualifications one will very soon become qualified to worship the Rādhā-Kṛṣṇa vigraha.

I have also read in many places (cited here - [What would please Lord Hanuman more - chanting Hanuman Chalisa or chanting Rama naam?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/29870/what-would-please-lord-hanuman-more-chanting-hanuman-chalisa-or-chanting-rama)) that worship of the Lord's devotee pleases Him more than worship of Him directly. So I want to worship Lord Sri Nityananda Rama Chandra Prabhu directly by chanting Nitaai (निताइ) nam. I want to know what would be the result.

For example worship of various demigods gives various results, like worship of Lord Ganesh removes obstacles, worship of Goddess Lakshmi or Goddess Durga increases material prosperity, worship of Lord Surya increases eyesight and gives better health etc. (can't find sources at the moment, but I've read these things on the internet and in Srila Prabhupada's books).

In your answers, citations from Srila Prabhupada's books or other Vaishnava acharyas' books would be really nice.

Comment: Who is saying  that Bhagavati Durga is a demi-god and etc? Is it you or the person you are quoting?

Comment: @Rickross Gaudiya Vaishnava authors use the word "demigod" in their writings and theology.

Comment: The result of worshipping Lord Nityananda is the same as worshipping Lord Balarama because it is said that Lord Krishna appeared as Sri Caitanya (Gauranga) and Lord Balarama appeared as Lord Nityananda (Nitai). And what you'll get as a result of that worship is already stated in the text you quoted from Srila Prabhupada, you'll be released of sins, you'll get mercy of Lord Nitai, and you'll become eligible to worship Sri Sri Radha-Krishna. It is advisable to worship Lord Gaura also together with Sri Nitai.

Comment: @TigerShroff the recommendation of Chaitanya mahaprabhu and nityananda prabhu is to worship Radha Krishna. Hence it is not appropriate to worship/chant Chaitanya and nityananda prabhu leaving aside Radha Krishna. Hence we do both. We invite blessings of pancatattva and then worship Radha Krishna or chant panca tattva mantra before each round of hare Krishna mantra.

Comment: @RaRa - did you read the whole purport to the verse I linked? It says very explicitly to only worship guru-gauranga or gaur-nityananda in the beginning and not to chant the hare krishna mahamantra or engage in radha-krishna deity worship.

Comment: @TigerShroff we can see how Srila Prabhupad dealt in when he preached if we are confused about something. As for as worship is concerned, it is true that he initially only installed gaur nitai and Jagannath baladeva subhadra deities rather than Radha Krishna since offenses to the former are not serious. With regards to chanting the Holy names, he always gave hare Krishna mantra right in the beginning itself along with gaur nitai names mainly panca tattva mantra because by mercy of panca tattva cf chanting will become pure meaning it leads to love of godhead.